# Xcode 15.0 beta 6 VisionOS ImmersiveSpace error

Tags: xcode, swiftui, visionos

When trying to create an ImmersiveSpace with new VisionOS SDK I get following error:

> Fatal error: SwiftUI Scene ImmersiveSpace requires a UISceneSessionRole of "UISceneSessionRoleImmersiveSpaceApplication" for key UIApplicationPreferredDefaultSceneSessionRole in the Application Scene Manifest.

But I have these keys/values in my info.plist [image]